# DetalView: как вывести текст с тегами html

Tags: php, yii2

Имеется виджет DetalView:

```
 <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'information:ntext',                
            [
                'attribute' => 'text',
                'value' => $model->getUserAttributes('getScientificWorks', 'text'),
            ],
         ],
    ])
    ?>
```

метод getUserAttributes отдаёт строку:

```
$string .= $item[$field] . ", ";
```

Если вместо запятой вставить тег переноса строки, то выведется как "текст <ВR> текст" 
Собственно, мне нужно вставить перенос строки.

Comment: Если между `attribute` и `value` вставить `'format'=>'raw',` - поможет?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, благодарю. Не нашел описания и примера опций.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужнен параметр raw он не фильтрует данные  и выводит как есть

html (html purified) or raw (not encode anything).

Comment: Ну подробнее что ли... Или отформатируй. Ну и хотя бы по-русски...